# In Magento, how does one load the block which contains the user defined customer registration custom attributes?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Just to give some context, I have made a separate checkout form, but I need to reinstate the custom attributes...  Hence my question how does one load the block which contains the user defined customer registration custom attributes?

I

Comment: Do you want to load them in your new Checkout form OR the customer add/edit form?

Comment: If you have found a solution to this problem. It is good to post it as an answer and accept it. It keeps the Stack overflow ecosystem going.

Comment: Still searching.   The form is within the checkout process... it is a stage 4, billing address, thuogh it could be used for different delivery address too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block has methods to determine if user defined variables are set:
app\code\core\Enterprise\Customer\Block\Form.php

This is the template which is used to generate them:
app\design\frontend\enterprise\default\template\customer\form\userattributes.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->hasUserDefinedAttributes()): ?>
    <?php if ($this->isShowContainer()): ?>
<div>
    <ul class="form-list">
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getUserDefinedAttributes() as $attribute):?>
        <?php $attributeContent = $this->getAttributeHtml($attribute);?>
        <?php if ($attributeContent): ?>
        <li><?php echo $attributeContent;?></li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php if ($this->isShowContainer()): ?>
    </ul>
</div>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It was hard to find since the magento version I was working on had been so heavily customised.

What i did was install a fresh out of the box version and see which blocks where being called:
Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute is the model (which resolves to model customer/attribute)
Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute (app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Attribute.php)